# How to search for dependencies for Java 8 yum install?

Tags: rhel, java, dependencies

I inherited `ansible` playbook that installs `java 1.8.0_181` via `yum` module on `rhel` server. My plan is to upgrade to `java 1.8.0_221`. While reviewing the playbook, I noticed it would install `copy-jdk-configs-3.3-9.el6.noarch.rpm` and `jpackage-utils-1.7.5-3.16.el6.noarch.rpm` as dependencies from comments I read.

Examples of how to install `java` I have seen so far don't mention any dependencies at all. My concern is if I upgrade to `1.8.0_221`, those dependencies still stand valid. If not, I need to determine what version of aforementioned rpm files I have to provide but I only gathered what they are in basic info and I have not found yet correlated info I can refer to between them (`Java vs copy-jdk-config/jpkg-utils`).

I would appreciate if someone can grant advice on following questions.

1. Why those dependencies are required
2. How to determine Java 1.8.0_221 require xyz version of copy-jdk-config and jpkg-utils

[update]

Using `rpm -qRp` cmd helped me to determine whether those dependencies are required or not. For `Java 1.8.0_181` does, but for `Java 1.8.0_221` does not it looks like.

Comment: Which JRE are you installing?  Because the latest OpenJDK is `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el6_10`. The dependencies are part of the package so I can’t tell which one you are looking at.

Comment: Oracle JDK/JRE sire. My apology..I should have clarified it first.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html

Comment: Have you downloaded the package?  Have you tried to run `rpm -qRp java-package-name.rpm` (using the correct package name, of course)

Comment: Ty for teaching me newbie like me on how to verify dependencies via `rpm` cmd.